# Tomcat7 and google chart issue with IE8

Tags: javascript, tomcat, internet-explorer-8, google-visualization

i did an application that uses google chart (line chart).
If i run it on my local instance of Tomcat7 the chart is displayed in IE8 but using the instance of Tomcat7 in the developement server it doesn't work with Internet Explorer (no errors but nothing is displayed.Using Chrome instead it works properly).

Here the source code generated in the browser of the local version :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Phone Cost System</title>
        <link class="component" href="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/s/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss/DATB/eAELXT5DOhSIAQ!sA18_.jsf" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link class="component" href="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/s/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/extended_classes.xcss/DATB/eAELXT5DOhSIAQ!sA18_.jsf" media="rich-extended-skinning" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link class="component" href="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/msg.css.jsf" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link class="component" href="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/msgs.css.jsf" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript.jsf" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">window.RICH_FACES_EXTENDED_SKINNING_ON=true;</script><script src="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/skinning.js.jsf" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="css/phoneCostSystem.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

      function drawChart(a) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses2');

    data.addRows(JSON.parse(a.test));


    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        pointSize : 2,       
        interpolateNulls: true

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

      }
    </script>


    </head>

<body onload="submitApplication()">
    <div id="overDiv" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden; z-index:1000;"></div>



            <div class="outer">
     <!-- START MAIN -->
                <div class="content">
                <div class="innercontent">
   <h4>My Expenses</h4>
    <dl id="myError" class="rich-messages errorMessage" style="display: none; "><dt></dt></dl>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/phoneCostSystem/charts.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="form1" value="form1" />


<div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
<script id="j_id_jsp_1252683611_4" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        submitApplication=function(){A4J.AJAX.Submit('form1',null,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){drawChart(data)},'similarityGroupingId':'j_id_jsp_1252683611_4','parameters':{'j_id_jsp_1252683611_4':'j_id_jsp_1252683611_4'} ,'containerId':'j_id_jsp_1252683611_0'} )};
        //]]></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //example callback function
        function processData(data) {   
            console.log(data);
            var temp=JSON.stringify(data); 
            alert(temp);

        }

        //call the ajax method from javascript

    </script>

<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="j_id2" />
</form>  



















        <br />
        <br />

        </div>
        </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the code generated if i run the app in developement server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Phone Cost System</title>
        <link class="component" href="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/s/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss/DATB/eAELXT5DOhSIAQ!sA18_.jsf" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link class="component" href="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/s/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/extended_classes.xcss/DATB/eAELXT5DOhSIAQ!sA18_.jsf" media="rich-extended-skinning" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link class="component" href="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/msg.css.jsf" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link class="component" href="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/msgs.css.jsf" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript.jsf" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">window.RICH_FACES_EXTENDED_SKINNING_ON=true;</script><script src="/phoneCostSystem/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/skinning.js.jsf" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="css/phoneCostSystem.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

      function drawChart(a) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses2');

    data.addRows(JSON.parse(a.test));


    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        pointSize : 2,       
        interpolateNulls: true

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

      }
    </script>


    </head>

<body onload="submitApplication()">
    <div id="overDiv" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden; z-index:1000;"></div>



            <div class="outer">
     <!-- START MAIN -->
                <div class="content">
                <div class="innercontent">
   <h4>My Expenses</h4>
    <dl id="myError" class="rich-messages errorMessage" style="display: none; "><dt></dt></dl>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/phoneCostSystem/charts.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="form1" value="form1" />


<div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
<script id="j_id_jsp_1829848551_4" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        submitApplication=function(){A4J.AJAX.Submit('form1',null,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){drawChart(data)},'similarityGroupingId':'j_id_jsp_1829848551_4','parameters':{'j_id_jsp_1829848551_4':'j_id_jsp_1829848551_4'} ,'containerId':'j_id_jsp_1829848551_0'} )};
        //]]></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //example callback function
        function processData(data) {   
            console.log(data);
            var temp=JSON.stringify(data); 
            alert(temp);

        }

        //call the ajax method from javascript

    </script>

<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="j_id2" />
</form>  



















        <br />
        <br />

        </div>
        </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea regarding a possible root cause?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the HTML/javascript produced by your server code (open the page in a browser, right click, and view source)?  Also, it might help to get the source from your local and dev environments, and use a diff tool to make sure that the server is rendering them the same in both cases.

Comment: Can you post example data returned by the AJAX call?

Comment: The only difference in the two code blocks is `j_id_jsp_1829848551_4` in the first document becomes `j_id_jsp_1252683611_4` in the second document. The problem is likely not in the actual HTML code.

Comment: Can the issue be related to something in Tomcat development environment that is not properly set?

Comment: I FOUND THE SOLUTION: Internet Explorer was set to run in compatibilitity view mode  in the intranet i use to connect to developement server and this cause the issue since JSON.parse is not supported.I fix the issue including JSON3 in the page.
<script src="http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>